# How to create new column on data frame as a result of call to rgeom

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to calculate to probability of an event occurring. So this is a two stage process: the probability of the event occuring and how long each event that occurs lasts

So i have used rbinom to get a vector of over 10000 iterations of how many time the event occurs. I then thought if I turned this into a dataframe I can use dplyr mutate to pass each individual row to the rgeom function as the n argument. However i get the same result for each row

year <- rbinom(10000, 8760, 0.0068)

mean(year)

year2 <- as.data.frame(year)

colnames(year2)[1] <- "test"

year3 <- year2 %>% mutate(year = sum(rgeom(test, 0.004)))

year3

I expect each row to have a different sum so for example

Test  year

65    500

45    411

as if you had called rgeom outside the mutate

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the problem is that you're setting year equal to the sum of the results of rgeom. There are 10000 different results, but only a single sum. I believe this is what you want:

```
year <- rbinom(10000, 8760, 0.0068)

mean(year)

year2 <- as.data.frame(year)

colnames(year2)[1] <- "test"

year3 <- year2 %>% mutate(year = rgeom(test, 0.004))

year3
```

Comment: You haven't summed the rgeom vector, as OP has requested.

Comment: Thanks, I had misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that a summary function like `sum()` with `mutate()` effectively summarises across the groups within the data. Since you have not applied any grouping, it sums across the entire data frame.

Anyway, I have two solutions for you. Firstly, using the `map_int` function from the `purrr` package - which applies the function iteratively to each element of the column you specify - in this case, the "test" column:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(1)
year <- 
  data.frame(test = rbinom(10000, 8760, 0.0068))

set.seed(1)
year3 <-
  year %>%
  mutate(year = map_int(test, ~sum(rgeom(., 0.04))))

head(year3)
#>   test year
#> 1   61 1369
#> 2   53 1430
#> 3   74 1568
#> 4   57 1483
#> 5   62 1294
#> 6   66 1619
```

Alternatively, you can group the data frame using `rowwise()` from `dplyr`, but I would caution against this since it is [tipped to be deprecated at some point](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3144#issuecomment-341530896):

```r
set.seed(1)
year <- 
  data.frame(test = rbinom(10000, 8760, 0.0068))

set.seed(1)
year3 <- 
  year %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(year = sum(rgeom(test, 0.04))) %>% 
  ungroup()

head(year3)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>    test  year
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1    61  1369
#> 2    53  1430
#> 3    74  1568
#> 4    57  1483
#> 5    62  1294
#> 6    66  1619
```